# Push failed - Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

when I try to run "git push heroku master", I get this error. This is my django project.

I have already run these commands

git init

git add .

git commit -m "first commit"

heroku login

heroku create votingsiteofsrm

```
(sepm) C:\Users\navee\projects\voting_portal>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 222, done.
Counting objects: 100% (222/222), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (218/218), done.
Writing objects: 100% (222/222), 3.58 MiB | 281.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 222 (delta 43), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to votingsiteofsrm.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/votingsiteofsrm.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/votingsiteofsrm.git'
```

Comment: And what did you learn by seeing `No default language could be detected for this app` and then going to the link shown in the HINT section immediately following that? What happened when you followed the advice at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks ?

Comment: thanks. I didn't read the documentation before. now there is no error